# I am having trouble with ASYNCTASK in my fragment

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I'm new to fragments.I am trying to call search API in my fragment using AsyncTask. Json Parsing is done in MainActivity, by the way I'm not in my main activity when I use this fragment, it's connected to another activity. It works, but I'm having trouble passing the parsed info that I stored into a bundle to a new fragment. To be specific it crashes the moment I try to open a new fragment. I have the parsed information and I've set the arguments for my fragment, it's just the moment I use .commit() it crashes.

Comment: Please post some of your codes so that we can help you.

Comment: please attach your logs where the crash is

Comment: How you handle json parsing in another activity? Provide code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great if you could post the piece of your code so we can check what is the issue.

Although I have deduced from your explanation that you might be saving the information in `doInBackground` which runs on the background thread. Instead, you could pass that info to the `onPostExecute` and save it into `SharedPreferences` since `onPostExecute` runs on the UI thread.

Let me know if this works.